# return values when any condition is met in SQL 'case when'

Tags: sql, case-when

how could I write a SQL that returns all values when any condition is met, just like below:

```
case when a = 'key' then 'good one'
case when a = 'key' then 'bad one'
```

from

```
id  a
1  key
```

to

```
id type
1  good one
2  bad one
```

It seems like converting single row to multiple rows

Comment: Why should `id` change? Is that a real field or something you need to calculate, or not needed? Please show the real table schema and sample input data. It sounds like you might just want two `select`s and a `union`, and maybe some `row_number()` or such, but then you'd need also to tag which RDBMS you are using to get relevant advice. And we'd need to know more about that mysterious `id` and how it should increment (or not?) for different source data, and whether that source data can contain other values of `a`, and etc. This is very unclear as currently written.

Comment: Can you post your complete data set

Comment: Join against a list of rows that spell out the possible combinations.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.id, x.type
from t join
     (select 'key' as a, 'good one' as type union all
      select 'key' as a, 'bad one' as type
     ) x
     on t.a = x.a;
```

Note:  You have not specified the database.  The above may not work specifically on your database, but something similar would.